# Syntax error: cannot recognize input near " " " in function specification

Tags: mysql, sql, hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am running following hive query in qubole

```
select locate(';', substring(tags, locate('Swimlane:', tags), 
            length(tags)))
from myTable
```

Error I am getting:

```
Syntax Error: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.parse.ParseException: line 1:15 
              cannot recognize input near '' '' '' in function specification
```

I am not able to find much online to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution, to find special character (; - in my case) you have to put escape character in front of it. so following solution would work

```
select locate('\;', substring(tags, locate('Swimlane:', tags), 
            length(tags)))
from myTable
```